# How to randomize ENUM-inputs in Postman?

Tags: json, enums, postman, postman-mocks

In Postman I send the POST-request with JSON-body. The field status has 9 predefined ENUM values: Opened, Reserved, Paid, Shipped, Delivered, Returned, PartlyReturned, Closed, Canceled. How can I randomize the value of this field while sending the new requests?

```
{
  "status": "Opened"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a= ["Opened", "Reserved", "Paid", "Shipped", "Delivered", "Returned", "PartlyReturned", "Closed", "Canceled"]


pm.environment.set("value", _.sample(a))
```

IN body use:

```
   {
  "status": "{{value}}"
   }
```

As Danny mentioned in comment above is the right way

Ignore below :

```
pm.environment.set("value",a[Math.floor(Math.random() * ((a.length-1) - 0 + 1) + 0)])
```

Add this to pre-request , now varaible value changes randomly . IN body use:

```
   {
  "status": "{{value}}"
   }
```

you can use in build dynamic variable $randomint also for this

```
a= ["Opened", "Reserved", "Paid", "Shipped", "Delivered", "Returned", "PartlyReturned", "Closed", "Canceled"]


random=pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomInt}}")

random = Math.floor((random/1000)*(a.length))

pm.environment.set("value",a[random])
```

Comment: Lodash could be used to simplify the code slightly `pm.environment.set("value", _.sample(a))` 

Comment: Completely forgot about lodash uff